# Wordpress registered users adding content or products

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use Wordpress in order to create a (somewhat) e-shop where users can register and make their offer(adding text and an image). The idea is that users will be able to 'post' offers. Are there any plugins that give such control to the user? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try below plugins ...

http://wordpress.org/plugins/another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/classyfrieds/